# Father's name in the birth certificate and Italian citizenship

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, italian-citizens, birth-certificate, italy-aire

When I arrived in the UK from Italy in 2003 I met a wonderful woman and we both fell in love. I could not even speak good English at that time, we used to go to the gym together, she had very long blonde hair.

Unfortunately, I was not ready for commitment at that time.

20 years after we still see each other regularly some periods more than others.
She is married and has 4 children with her husband.
I am married and I have 3 children with my wife.

This year we decided to have a child.
We did not think it all through, all the implications.

I feel that for me to satisfy God, and my ancestors, **I need to pass onto my new daughter** (*yes she is a girl and she looks a lot like me - we saw in the 4G scan - she is 30 weeks now*) **Italian citizenship**.

However, because we want to keep it undisclosed to the school and all people not closely related to us, that she has a different father to the one who is raising her, we agreed and I agreed that my surname - Giuliani - will no need to be in her name, but I want it to be in her birth certificate - because of the Italian heritage.

Can I have my name in her birth certificate and at the same time my family name will not be her family name?

for example her name is Annie Faith Jones, only.
but in her birth certificate there will be said that the father is: Salvatore Giuliani.

Or would it be a requirement that her name be Annie Faith Giuliani?

Would this be accepted by the Italian consulate?

PS - I am very happy and very thankful for this baby.

PS2 -  I am asking about the process of registering a child born abroad.

I am also looking for clarification regarding  the child's eligibility to Italian citizenship.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this may probably be more suitable on law@SE

Comment: The rules on what can be included in a birth certificate issued in the UK are explained here https://www.gov.uk/register-birth/who-can-register-a-birth

Comment: @littleadv No, this is a **pure** Expatriates issue, since this procedure can **only** be done through the AIRE system of the responsible kocal consulate. Voting to reopen so that an answer can be given.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the question was closed by a moderator. I don't know what AIRE system is, but the question seems to be about the legal options to register birth in the UK and about Italian citizenship law, both are *legal* questions.

Comment: @littleadv You started the close procedure. Registration of a child born abroad is a consulate affair.

Comment: Yes, @MarkJohnson, I know that. But the OP isn't asking about the process of registering a child born abroad. The OP is asking about very specific set of circumstances and how they affect the child's eligibility to Italian citizenship. If you know the answer - feel free to answer at law@SE, you don't have to be a lawyer to post there.

Comment: @littleadv And the answer to that is that a registration at the responsible local consulate through the AIRE, where he himself must be registered since he lives outside of Italy. That is why a italy-aire tag exists here. As a member of law.se (which you are not) I can say since this is a pure consulate procedure it belongs to expatriates and not law.

Comment: but the question is not about registration...

Comment: @littleadv From the OP: 'I need to give my new daughter (...) the Italian citizenship.' To get the Italian citizenship recognised he must registerer his child at the responsible local consulate through the AIRE system, where he himself must be registered since he lives outside of Italy. If this is now clear to you, then vote to reopen so that I can submit the prepaired answer to the OP question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the problem here has much less to do with the administrative details of the registration process and much more to do with the questions of whether a child born to a married woman can have a man other than her husband listed on the UK birth certificate and whether, if this man were listed as the father, the UK birth certificate could show her surname as that of her mother's husband and, if so, whether the Italian consulate would accept this as the child's name.  These are legal questions.

Comment: @phoog And the place to get this advice, is where it is actualy done: The Registry office (Stato Civile) of the Italian Consulate.

Comment: Ok, I've voted to reopen.  The interplay between UK law and Italian law brings the situation within the scope of this site.

Comment: @phoog Thank You.

Comment: See [Questions that fall within the scope of consulate functions for their citizens should not be closed - Expatriates Meta Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/q/451/17166)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have my name in her birth certificate and at the same time my family name will not be her family name?

In the link provided by @Traveller, the following can be found:

- [Statutory declaration of acknowledgement of parentage form - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/statutory-declaration-of-acknowledgement-of-parentage-form)

Here you would acknowledge the child as yours. No mention as to the family name conventions.

You and the mother should read this carefully to insure that it is what you want (especially the **Parental Responsibility** part, since this may not be desired).

> Would this be accepted by the Italian consulate?

The *Registry office (Stato Civile)* of the Italian Consulate would be the best place to ask this (especially if the British *Statutory declaration of acknowledgement of parentage form* is strictly required).

It may be sufficient to make such a declaration at the Stato Civile office avoiding any possible *Parental Responsibility* complications.

> [Frequently asked questions - AIRE (London)](https://conslondra.esteri.it/consolato_londra/en/la_comunicazione/domande_frequenti/faq-aire.html)
> **8. A child is born in the UK how do I proceed with the AIRE registration?**
>
> The procedure in this case is processed and completed by the [Registry office (Stato Civile) of the Italian Consulate](https://conslondra.esteri.it/consolato_londra/en/i_servizi/per_i_cittadini/stato_civile) and will be forwarded to the relevant Italian town hall (Comune). Please visit the Registry office (Stato Civile) web page for details on the procedure to register the birth of a child in the UK.
>
> > [Registry office (Stato Civile) of the Italian Consulate (London)](https://conslondra.esteri.it/consolato_londra/en/i_servizi/per_i_cittadini/stato_civile)
> > The Registry Office (statocivile.londra@esteri.it) deals with the registration of British birth, marriage certificates, entries in the Civil Partnership RegIstry and divorce decrees relating to Italian citizens.
> >
> > The Registry Office forwards the above-mentioned certificates to the relevant Italian ‘’Comune’’ (Town Hall) to obtain referenced registration.

Once the Comune registration process has been completed, the consulate will add your daughter to the AIRE system (I assume as your dependent). With that done, you can apply for an Italian passport for your daughter.